# Here Maps SDK iOS Swift 3 Documentation

Tags: ios, swift, here-api

is there any further documentation of the `Here Maps SDK` for `Swift`? I have only found a simple `mapView` and nothing more.

Thanks for all your tips!

Comment: There is no official Swift support right now, so also no explicit Swift documentation. Here's a more advanced Swift example with routing that could be handy: https://tcs.ext.here.com/sdk_examples/ExtendedSwiftExample.zip (still Swift2.2/Xcode7 based)

Comment: Thanks for you sample in swift. Great work done by you @Marco

Comment: btw, the mentioned example is also now up to date with XCode8 and Swift3

Answer (score 2):

Unless this is what you were referring to, you might find this site useful. It seems to include more extensive topics than just mapViews.

This comes from the developer.here.com website:

[Here iOS SDK Documentation](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/ios-hybrid-plus/topics/user-guide.html)

If you're looking for more depth than this, you might be out of luck. I have just performed some research on this topic and it doesn't seem to me that Here has extensive online resources.

This might be from the original site as well, but you can also check out [this list of examples](http://heremaps.github.io/examples/) for inspiration/help.

Of course you can also refer to StackOverflow as a resource as well, as I have seen some posts about this service that have been posted on the site, so they may help with some of the problems you are facing.